# In Pig, can you do a replicated left join?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

The documentation is somewhat misleading when it comes to replicated joins in Pig.  The script won't compile if I add 'left' to the join and also using 'replicated'.  The documentation mentions only supporting left outer joins with replicated, but the behavior is obviously an inner join.  Does anyone know how to do a left replicated join?

```
c = join a by (x,y,z) left, b by (x,y,z) using 'replicated';
```

(That statement won't parse)

Answer (score 1):

replicated join can work with either inner or left outer join, and it works for me with 3 fields. what's the error message you're getting? are you sure the fields are of compatible data types? what's your pig version?

Comment: I get this: mismatched input 'left' expecting SEMI_COLON

Comment: can you share your script? With this simple script it works for me on 0.11.0-cdh4.4.0: 1   a = load '/tmp' as (x:int, y:int, z:int);
2   b = load '/tmp' as (x:int, y:int, z:int);
3   c = join a by (x,y,z) left, b by (x,y,z) using 'replicated';